# How can I completely disable HTML responses with the Google Assistant SDK?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to disable the HTML5 responses from [google-assistant-sdk](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/) and receive only text responses.

The Google Assistant SDK documentation has a [ScreenMode](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2#google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2.ScreenOutConfig.ScreenMode) parameter, which seems to be used to disable 'card' (html) responses, but even when set to OFF, some queries such as "Who was the first astronaut" always return HTML content, regardless of [ScreenMode](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2#google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2.ScreenOutConfig.ScreenMode).

**How can I completely disable HTML5 responses and just get text responses?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried leaving ScreenMode unset or set it to SCREEN_MODE_UNSPECIFIED?

I use the following Java code and I never see HTML:

```
ScreenOutConfig screenOutConfig = ScreenOutConfig.newBuilder()
    //.setScreenMode(ScreenOutConfig.ScreenMode.PLAYING)
    .build();
```

When I want to test HTML output, I uncomment the middle line.

Comment: Oddly enough, when I test your specific question "who was the first astronaut", and I pass in OFF or SCREEN_MODE_UNSPECIFIED, I don't get back HTML but I also don't get back supplemental display text either.  Strange because I almost always get something back for supplemental display text.